# Redux-Persist Library - Save data from counter to localStorage

Tags: redux, persist

Good day,

The beginnings of learning redux can be confusing

The steps in this code:

- Create reducer for increment
- Create Store
- If user takes `onClick` action, function increment dispatch previously mentioned reducer
- In this same component display data
- Render component inside Provider with store

In this case need is saving the state with data to LocalStorage.

What should I do for save **counter_state** to **local-storage**?

```
// reducer
function counter(state=0, action) {
  console.log('counter', action)
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;

      return state;
  }
}

///create store
const store = createStore(counter);

// React Component

class Counter extends React.Component {
  increment() {
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'INCREMENT'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      {this.props.state}
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {state};
}

const CounterApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter);

class Test5 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <CounterApp />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default Test5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage has a pretty simple interface. I'd recommend looking up its API on mdn. Since you're not using any of the persistence libraries you're importing, might as well try it directly for learning purposes:

1. Write the value of `state.counter` to localStorage in your `mapStateToProps`
2. When you do `createStore` you can pass a second argument with preloadedState. So before you do that, read from localStorage to get the saved value of your counter.

Some remarks:

- `state` in the reducer is usually an object with properties. It might work with a simple number, but if you want to learn redux you'll want to use an object here.
- I'd recommend to move on to the more complicated libraries like `redux-persist` once you feel comfortable with the basics of redux. It's too much abstraction at once for getting a simple counter to work.